# Sudo options question

Tags: server, sudo, cron

I need to run a command that requires sudo to run and I want to run it in crontab -e
the command is sudo java -jar WurmMapGen.jar  but it asks for a password.  I want this to be an automatic unattended type thing where it runs at 2 am every morning.  How do I use sudo but get it where it doesnt ask for a password?

Comment: Run it as the root user's `crontab`.  So, as the root user, type `crontab -e` instead.  Then you will end up adding to sudo's `crontab` and not your's.

Comment: @Ray  I do not know how to enable the Root user on this server or if that is even possible